# How do I access an import within a class?

Tags: javascript, scope, react-native, require

Using the debugger in chrome, `ImagePicker` is set, but when I try to call it in the select() function, `ImagePicker` is undefined.

I am having the same issue on other modules as well, so I suspect it's something to do with the way i'm importing it or a scoping issue.

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
} from 'react-native';
import Button from 'react-native-button';

var ImagePicker = require('react-native-image-picker');

// I tried this also, but it doesn't set at all.
// import { ImagePicker } from 'react-native-image-picker';

export class Upload extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Button
                    style={styles.button}
                    onPress={this.select.bind(this)}>
                    Upload
                </Button>
            </View>
        );
    }
    select() {
        var options = {...};

        ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: by "access" do you mean "make public"? make one of your class methods return the `ImagePicker` constructor.

Comment: try `import * as ImagePicker  from 'react-native-image-picker';`

Comment: @Maxx when I get to `ImagePicker.showImagePicker()` the console says that ImagePicker is an object now, but when i try to step over that it still says `Cannot read property 'showImagePicker' of undefined`. It's defined but it think it's not?

Comment: Unfortunately sometimes using the debugger to check out values of an object is not the most reliable. As you have mentioned here when you `console.log` it you can see what the object contains, but when debugging things like this can sometimes be undefined. I'm not sure what causes this and when I run across it I usually just console log until I've finished whatever feature or bug I'm working on and move on from there. :/

Comment: Ok, I found out this was an issue with ReactNative not seeing the libraries even though they were imported into xcode. I am using the Deco IDE which needs to run 'Build Native Modules' i guess to include those custom modules when it runs xcode via it's own commands